# Pug APi doesn't work

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, pug, pugjs

Can anyone tell me why pug api doesn't work with simple example from theirs documentation page

```
const pug = require('pug');

// Compile the source code
const compiledFunction = pug.compileFile('template.pug');

// Render a set of data
console.log(compiledFunction({
  name: 'Timothy'
}));
// "<p>Timothy's Pug source code!</p>"
```

No metter what i do it keeps telling pug.compileFile is not a function

Answer (score 0):

The given code works perfectly fine for me. Here's a [Glitch instance](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/longing-train) I made to test this out. Notice that the console correctly logs out the compiled HTML from the `template.pug` template.

Having said that, please make sure you've done the following correctly:

- Installed Pug and saved it to your package.json: `npm install pug --save`
- Have a valid `template.pug` file at the correct location

Take a look at the Glitch instance and you might figure out what the problem is.